# Creating a value in one column based on string match in any of multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains possible values "c1", "c2", "c3", or "no" for multiple rows, and in multiple columns.  Any given row contains either "no" or *just one* of the other values ... that is, no row contains both c1 and c2.

What I want to do is create a new column which contains the non-"no" value of each row, if *any* of the columns contains the non-"no" value; otherwise stays "no."  This ought to be simple, I think, but I'm not getting it.

Here's sample data ... save as "test1.csv"

```
Group1,Group2,Group3,Group4,Group5,Group6
c1,no,no,c1,no,no
no,no,c1,no,no,no
no,no,no,no,c1,no
no,no,no,no,no,no
c1,no,no,no,no,c1
no,c1,no,no,no,no
c2,no,no,no,no,no
no,c2,no,c2,no,no
no,no,no,no,no,no
no,no,no,no,no,c2
c3,no,c3,no,c3,no
no,no,no,no,no,no
no,no,c3,c3,no,no
```

Here's what I've tried to do:

```
df <- read.csv("test1.csv")
df$any <- "no"
df$any[df == "c1"] <- "c1"
df$any[df == "c2"] <- "c2"
df$any[df == "c3"] <- "c3"
```

Which returns the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, any, value = c("c1", "no", "no", "no",  : 
  replacement has 91 rows, data has 13
```

Successful output should look like this:

```
   Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 Group6 any
1      c1     no     no     c1     no     no  c1
2      no     no     c1     no     no     no  c1
3      no     no     no     no     c1     no  c1
4      no     no     no     no     no     no  no
5      c1     no     no     no     no     c1  c1
6      no     c1     no     no     no     no  c1
7      c2     no     no     no     no     no  c2
8      no     c2     no     c2     no     no  c2
9      no     no     no     no     c2     no  c2
10     no     no     no     no     no     no  no
11     c3     no     c3     no     c3     no  c3
12     no     no     no     no     no     no  no
13     no     no     c3     c3     no     no  c3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `max.col` we can extract the first value in the row which is not `"no"`. Since every row would have same non-"no" value ties would not matter here or you can specify `ties.method = "first"` to get first non-"no" value.

```
df$any <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df != "no"))]

df
#   Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 Group6 any
#1      c1     no     no     c1     no     no  c1
#2      no     no     c1     no     no     no  c1
#3      no     no     no     no     c1     no  c1
#4      no     no     no     no     no     no  no
#5      c1     no     no     no     no     c1  c1
#6      no     c1     no     no     no     no  c1
#7      c2     no     no     no     no     no  c2
#8      no     c2     no     c2     no     no  c2
#9      no     no     no     no     no     no  no
#10     no     no     no     no     no     c2  c2
#11     c3     no     c3     no     c3     no  c3
#12     no     no     no     no     no     no  no
#13     no     no     c3     c3     no     no  c3
```

Comment: @DanM Can you explain that with an example? In which case would there be values other than the value in the column and what output would you expect in those cases?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` method

```
df1$any <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[x != 'no'][1])
df1$any[is.na(df1$any)] <- "no"
df1$any
#[1] "c1" "c1" "c1" "no" "c1" "c1" "c2" "c2" "c2" "no" "c3" "no" "c3"
```

---

Or another option with `pmin` in `base R`

```
df1$any <- do.call(pmin, df1)
df1$any
#[1] "c1" "c1" "c1" "no" "c1" "c1" "c2" "c2" "c2" "no" "c3" "no" "c3"
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(any = pmin(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))))
```

Answer (score 1):

It might make sense to store your `"no"`s as missing values, in which case the extra column is all the other columns `coalesce`d

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(na_if, 'no') %>% 
  mutate(any = reduce(., coalesce))

#    Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 Group6  any
# 1      c1   <NA>   <NA>     c1   <NA>   <NA>   c1
# 2    <NA>   <NA>     c1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   c1
# 3    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     c1   <NA>   c1
# 4    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> <NA>
# 5      c1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     c1   c1
# 6    <NA>     c1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   c1
# 7      c2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   c2
# 8    <NA>     c2   <NA>     c2   <NA>   <NA>   c2
# 9    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> <NA>
# 10   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     c2   c2
# 11     c3   <NA>     c3   <NA>     c3   <NA>   c3
# 12   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> <NA>
# 13   <NA>   <NA>     c3     c3   <NA>   <NA>   c3
```